# JavaScript in Live Cycle Designer

Tags: jquery, livecycle

I have a list of approx 50 tv channels that a sales rep can select from a list of about 150. The channels selected then must appear on another page in alphabetical order. They must be in a list that can be manually corrected if a channel is added. I have used check boxes and radio buttons to make things visible or invisible but is there a way to just generate a word associated with the check box and make it appear on another page and in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 0):

For my solution to this problem, I created a subform with 10 checkboxes, then I created a subform with 10 text fields (your channel list and other list with channel descriptions, respectively). Then I made a button with the following code on the click event.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if (xfa.resolveNode("p1.sfChannelList.CheckBox1["+i+"]").rawValue == "1")
    xfa.resolveNode("p2.sfResult.Text1["+i+"]").presence = "visible";
    else xfa.resolveNode("form1.p1.sfResult.Text1["+i+"]").presence = "hidden";
}
```

I made the checkboxes by copy/pasting one so that they'd all have the same name; similarly, I created the text fields in the second subform.